# Adding button in a pdf file using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, forms, pdf, itext, field

I want to add a button in an existing pdf using itextsharp. I found examples to add text field but I am not able to get any example to add a button at a particular location in a pdf file.

Answer (score 3):

Use the PdfStamper to add a PushbuttonField to an existing PDF.  Specify a position on a page, a name for the field, and the page number.

```
static void AddPushbuttonField(string inputFile, iTextSharp.text.Rectangle buttonPosition, string buttonName, string outputFile)
{
    using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(new PdfReader(inputFile), File.Create(outputFile)))
    {
        PushbuttonField buttonField = new PushbuttonField(stamper.Writer, buttonPosition, buttonName);

        stamper.AddAnnotation(buttonField.Field, 1);
        stamper.Close();
    }
}
```

You should also take a look at iText in Action.  [Chapter 8](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=8) has examples of creating a PushbuttonField and many of the different properties you can set.